# Failed to update the empty array in mobx store under strict mode

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

I am getting the error below when I try to update the observable arrays in mobx store even if I wrap the mutations under the action. (runInAction() method).
**Mobx version(5.5.14) and mobx-react(6.2.2)**

```
    Error: [mobx] Since strict-mode is enabled, changing observed observable values outside actions is 
not allowed. Please wrap the code in an `action` if this change is intended. 
Tried to modify: BusinessStore@9.expenseChartData
▶ 33 stack frames were collapsed.
BusinessStore.handleExpenseMetrics
/stores/businessStore.js:188
  185 |         this.dashboardMetrics.totalExpenses = metricObj.totalExpenses
  186 |      })
  187 |       
> 188 |      runInAction(()=>{
      | ^  189 |         this.expenseChartLabels = metricObj.expenseChartLabels
  190 |      }) //this is just short fix for updates for many arrays in objects
  191 |
```

This is how the dashboard code looks like that invokes the action.

```
- Dashboard.jsx.
loadExpenseMetrics(inputDetails)
       .then(result=>{
          const totalExpenses =  calculateTotalExpense(result.chartData)
          
          const updateMetrics = {
             totalExpenses:totalExpenses,
             expenseChartLabels:result.labels, // ["Travel","Office", "Food"]
             expenseChartData:result.chartData // [30000, 560000,89000]
          }
          this.props.bizStore.handleExpenseMetrics(updateMetrics)
        })
```

This is how the observable arrays are initialised.

```
//businessStore.
      @observable expenseChartLabels =  []
      @observable expenseChartData = []
      @observable dashboardLoaded = false

      @observable dashboardMetrics = {
         totalRevenue: 0,
         totalExpenses: 0,
         totalCostSales: 0,
         saleOrderRevenue: 0,
         saleOrderCosts: 0,
         metricPeriod: 'Today'
      }
      
      handleExpenseMetrics(metricObj){
          runInAction(()=>{
             this.dashboardMetrics.totalExpenses = metricObj.totalExpenses
          })
       
          runInAction(()=>{
             this.expenseChartLabels = metricObj.expenseChartLabels
          }) //facing th error here... help with fix for it without removing the strict mode,

          runInAction(()=>{
             this.expenseChartData = metricObj.expenseChartData
          })
      }
```

**Surprisingly**
this problem only shows up for observable arrays but does not show up for normal strings and numbers. Actually the code below works perfectly well yet it involves multiple states values that are modified.

```
@action handleDashboardMetrics(metricsObj){

      runInAction(()=>{
         let dashMetrics = this.dashboardMetrics;
         dashMetrics.totalRevenue = metricsObj.totalRevenue
         dashMetrics.totalCostSales = metricsObj.totalCostSales
         dashMetrics.metricPeriod  = metricsObj.metricPeriod  
      })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, that's very weird. Judging by your code everything should work fine, and I actually tried to reproduce it in sandbox, but couldn't https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions63662962-ni4rh?file=/src/index.js (Look at the console, no errors there)

One thing you could check is MobX version, are you using latest? Maybe it is a bug in some older version?

Also, there is actually no need to use `runInAction` here, since you could just wrap your function in `@action` decorator like so:

```
      @action
      handleExpenseMetrics(metricObj){
          this.dashboardMetrics.totalExpenses = metricObj.totalExpenses
          this.expenseChartLabels = metricObj.expenseChartLabels
          this.expenseChartData = metricObj.expenseChartData
      }
```

Then all synchronous code inside function body will be run inside action.

Comment: i have tried the above code but the problem still persists. The funny thing is that above problem only shows up for observable arrays.. But otherwise I am able to modify state for numbers and strings multiple times in another action call

Comment: I will take a look at that code snippet you wrote in code sandbox tomorrow since it is late this side

Comment: actually the codesandbox snippet  you created  works perfectly fine.. Should my environment be a factor since i am using mobx in `electronjs` project. maybe let me try upgrading to `mobx version - 5.15.6`, the one you used.

Comment: @danilla , I have updated the mobx and mobx-react libraries to the latest version but the problem still persists.

Comment: Could you try my example from codesandbox in your electronjs app?

Comment: surprisingly your code sandbox works perfectly fine in mobx store without bringing those actions not allowed to modify.  I dont why it is behaving like if I use actions from the react component

Comment: @danilla, the above error shows up in the `setTimeout ` function.. so in the second update for mobx is where it is shows up.